# How to display parsed XML to ListView

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-studio

Currently I'm a beginner in android and right now I'm trying to display my parse xml data into a ListView. But I don't know how to display the data into a ListView. Can anyone assist me in solving this ? Here is my full source code.

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();



    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //new ReadRSS(this,"http://www.thestar.com.my/rss/editors-choice/main/").execute();
    //new ReadRSS(this,"http://www.sciencemag.org/rss/news_current.xml").execute();
    //new ReadRSS(this,"https://www.androidpit.com/feed/main.xml").execute();
    new ReadRSS(this,"http://malaysiakini.com/en/news.rss").execute();


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

`ReadRSS.java`

```
public class ReadRSS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

//Initialize progress dialog
Context context;
String address;
//String[] parts = address.split(";");
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
XmlPullParserFactory xmlPullParserFactory;
volatile boolean parsingComplete = true;
ArrayList<FeedItem> feedItems = new ArrayList<>();


public ReadRSS(Context context, String retrieveAddress) {
    //Create a new progress dialog
    this.address = retrieveAddress;
    this.context = context;
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading....");

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    //Display progress dialog
    progressDialog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
}

// This is run in a background thread
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    //ProcessXml(Getdata());
    fetchXML();
    return null;
}

// This is called from background thread but runs in UI
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

// This runs in UI when background thread finishes
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    //Dismiss progress dialog
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    progressDialog.dismiss();

}

 public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
    int event;
    String text=null;

    try {
        event = myParser.getEventType();
        FeedItem item = new FeedItem();

        while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String tagName = myParser.getName();

            switch (event){

                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if(tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                        int eventChild = myParser.next();

                            while(eventChild != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
                                String tagNameChild = myParser.getName();

                                switch (eventChild){

                                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                                        break;

                                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                                        text = myParser.getText();
                                        break;

                                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

                                        if(tagNameChild.equalsIgnoreCase("title")){
                                            item.setTitle(text);
                                            //Log.d("Title",text);
                                        }

                                        else if(tagNameChild.equalsIgnoreCase("link")){
                                            item.setLink(text);
                                            //Log.d("Link",text);
                                        }

                                        else if(tagNameChild.equalsIgnoreCase("description")){

                                            String plain = Html.fromHtml(text).toString();
                                            //stripHtml(text);
                                            item.setDescription(plain);
                                           // Log.d("Description",plain);
                                        }

                                        else if(tagNameChild.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")){
                                            item.setPubDate(text);
                                            //Log.d("pudDate",text);
                                        }

                                        else if(tagNameChild.equalsIgnoreCase("media:thumbnail") || tagNameChild.equalsIgnoreCase("media:content") || tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("enclosure")){

                                            //Output test
                                            if(myParser.getAttributeValue(null,"url") != null) {
                                                item.setThumbnailUrl(text);
                                                //Log.d("ItemThumbnailUrl",myParser.getAttributeValue(null,"url"));
                                            }
                                        }

                                        else if(tagNameChild.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                                            feedItems.add(item);
                                            //Log.d("ArrayList ",item.getTitle());
                                    }

                                        break;

                                }
                                eventChild = myParser.next();
                            }
                    }
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    break;

            }

            event = myParser.next();
        }

        parsingComplete = false;
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

   public void fetchXML(){
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                URL url = new URL(address);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                conn.setReadTimeout(10000 );
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 );
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);

                // Starts the query
                conn.connect();
                InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

                xmlPullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                XmlPullParser myparser = xmlPullParserFactory.newPullParser();

                myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                myparser.setInput(stream, null);

                parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
                stream.close();
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}



}
```

`content_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:layout_weight="0.09" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/date_text"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="0.05" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I would look at RecyclerViews and CardViews(https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You will have to basically store the data you passed from XML into a a custom ArrayList.
- Then make a custom list adapter and pass the arraylist to it. (tutorial: http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92)
- Store the parsed data at the end of the asynctask.

Comment: Base on my code, can you check whether I manage to store the data into the ArrayList properly ?

Comment: Can I know how do I add data into the ArrayList ?